# Registry pattern with __init_subclass__ and sub-classable registry

Tags: python, class, oop, metaclass, registry-pattern

I want to create a settings registry. I also want to be able to group settings in macro-categories.

The following simplified example works with a single registry:

```
class RegistryHolder:
    registry = {}

    def __init_subclass__(cls, setting_name=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.registry[setting_name] = cls

class SettingOne(RegistryHolder, setting_name='SettingOne'):
    pass

class SettingTwo(RegistryHolder, setting_name='SettingTwo'):
    pass
```

And the result is:

```
print(RegistryHolder.registry)

{'SettingOne': <class '__main__.SettingOne'>,
 'SettingTwo': <class '__main__.SettingTwo'>}
```

I would like to group the settings by macro categories without rewriting the  `__init_subclass__()` each time. Something like:

```
class UserRegistryHolder(RegistryHolder):
    pass

class SettingOne(UserRegistryHolder, setting_name='SettingOne'):
    pass

class SettingTwo(UserRegistryHolder, setting_name='SettingOne'):
    pass
```

```
class SystemRegistryHolder(RegistryHolder):
    pass

class SettingA(SystemRegistryHolder, setting_name='SettingA'):
    pass

class SettingB(SystemRegistryHolder, setting_name='SettingB'):
    pass
```

This obviously does not work because when I subclass the `RegistryHolder`, I am 'registering' the `User/System` classes as part of the registry, e.g. for `UserRegistryHolder.registry` I get:

```
{'SettingOne': <class '__main__.SettingTwo'>, 
 'SettingTwo': <class '__main__.SettingTwo'>, 
 None: <class '__main__.UserRegistryHolder'>}
```

So a few questions:

- Am I aksing the wrong question?
- Am I overthinking it?
- How would you go about creating such an interface cleanly (alternatives are welcome)?

Comment: let's elaborate: `RegistryHolder` is only a base class and should not accumulate all settings, while its sub-holders `User/System` should do that, right?

Comment: It seems like you aren't differentiating between registries and registry holders. `SettingA` is a registry, not a registry holder. (Or possibly, you want to distinguish between registry holders and registry-holder holders.)

Comment: What would you like this settings registry with grouped settings in macro-categories to look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `RegistryHolder` is only a base class (template) and should not accumulate all settings, while its sub-holders `UserRegistryHolder/SystemRegistryHolder` are expected do keep the "respective" settings:

```
class RegistryHolder:
    registry = {}

    def __init_subclass__(cls, setting_name=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        parent = cls.__bases__[0]
        if setting_name:
            parent.registry[setting_name] = cls  # add setting to parent sub-holder
        else:
            cls.registry = {}   # init registry for sub-holder


class UserRegistryHolder(RegistryHolder):
    pass

class SettingOne(UserRegistryHolder, setting_name='SettingOne'):
    pass

class SettingTwo(UserRegistryHolder, setting_name='SettingTwo'):
    pass

class SystemRegistryHolder(RegistryHolder):
    pass

class SettingA(SystemRegistryHolder, setting_name='SettingA'):
    pass

class SettingB(SystemRegistryHolder, setting_name='SettingB'):
    pass


print(RegistryHolder.registry)
print(UserRegistryHolder.registry)
print(SystemRegistryHolder.registry)
```

The output (consecutively):

```
{}
{'SettingOne': <class '__main__.SettingOne'>, 'SettingTwo': <class '__main__.SettingTwo'>}
{'SettingA': <class '__main__.SettingA'>, 'SettingB': <class '__main__.SettingB'>}
```